# MongoDB: Lookup Best Possible Match within Array [Mongoose]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here's the People **database:**

```
[
  #1 {qualities: ['brown', 'nice', 'happy' 'cool' 'cheery']}
  #2 {qualities: ['blue', 'okay', 'happy' 'decent' 'cheery']}
  #3 {qualities: ['green', 'alright', 'happy' 'cool' 'cheery']}
]
```

Here's the People **schema and model:**

```
var peopleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  qualities: [],
});

var People = mongoose.model('People', peopleSchema);
```

Here's the query that **actually works**:

```
People.find({'qualities': "cheery"}, function(err, people) {
   console.log(people)
});
```

### ^^ Problem: Can't use more than one word. ^^

Here's the type of query that **I'd like**:

```
People.find({'qualities': ["brown", "happy", "cool"]}, function(err, persons) {
  console.log(persons)
});
```

Hopeful result would be person #1 followed by person #3 followed by person #2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator

```
{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }
```

so query can be like

```
People.find({'qualities': {$in: ["brown", "happy", "cool"]}}, function(err, persons) {
  console.log(persons)
});
```

If you want to get data according to maximum match document first then you need to use aggregate query

say your data like:

```
{_id:1, qualities: ['brown', 'nice', 'happy' 'cool' 'cheery']}
{_id:2, qualities: ['blue', 'okay', 'happy' 'decent' 'cheery']}
{_id:3, qualities: ['green', 'alright', 'happy' 'cool' 'cheery']}
```

then your query will be like

```
People.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$qualities"},
  {$match:{'qualities': {$in: ["brown", "happy", "cool"]}}},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id",count:{$sum:1}}},
  {$sort:{count:-1}}
]).exec(function(err, persons) {
      console.log(persons)
});
```

it will return **1, 3,2** because for **first one** matched with *3*
 items, **third one** matched with *2* items and **second one** matched with *1* item

Comment: Then do the sorting of best possible match after the fact? Cool thanks.

Comment: Hey Shaishab I checked out your profile and was hoping to ask you another Mongo question as it appears you're an expert. 

Your answer is excellent and works fast for my database of 10,000 people - in fact, it completed in 273.199ms.

However, how will it fare for a db of 10 million entries? If these rates are proportional [100k:2.7s, 1m:27s, 10m:4m30s], it could take 4 minutes and 30 seconds. 

Perhaps the rate is not proportional, I do not yet know. But is there any optimization or suggestions for querying such a large database if my time hypothesis happens to be true?

Comment: Well, for huge amount of records you should apply pagination concept to search data that means should apply `$skip` and `$limit` in aggregate query. For example if you have 10000 records then you can show 100 records in your first page and then when clicked to next page then return another 100 records and so on. So your query will be much faster. thanks